# Build file: "no target" in "no project" (compiler: unknown)

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I wrote a code in c/c++. After correcting all the errors, I tried to compile and build it and I get this error log:

```
-------------- Build file: "no target" in "no project" (compiler: unknown)---------------

gcc -std=c11  -c /sysroot/home/arij/tryvache.c -o /sysroot/home/arij/tryvache.o
gcc  -o /sysroot/home/arij/tryvache /sysroot/home/arij/tryvache.o   
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/ld : /sysroot/home/arij/tryvache.o : dans la fonction « vache » :
tryvache.c:(.text+0x130) : référence indéfinie vers « pow »
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/ld : tryvache.c:(.text+0x1f7) : référence indéfinie vers « pow »
collect2: erreur: ld a retourné le statut de sortie 1
      Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
0 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: You probably forgot `-lm` somewhere in the linker flags. `gcc  -o /sysroot/home/arij/tryvache /sysroot/home/arij/tryvache.o` should be `gcc  -lm -o /sysroot/home/arij/tryvache /sysroot/home/arij/tryvache.o`

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the error message you have posted in the OP, I think it translates to

```
tryvache.c:(.text+0x130) : Undefined reference to 'pow'
```

used in `tryvache.c`

You must compile the code with flag `-lm` which instructs your compiler (gcc) to link with math library which contains `pow()` function.

If you have written the makefile all by yourself then you can simply add `-lm` as instructed in the comment above. If you are using an IDE like eclipse, then you will have to go though compiler options and/or build settings to find a correct section where the linker flags (such as -`lm`) needs to be added.

On eclipse IDE these are usually at GCC C Linker > libraries under the C/C++ Build settings.

Side note: It will be better if you setup your toolchain in English, if not, at least translate the errors for the people trying to solve your problem.